# Add/fire script file dynamicly on route change Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, ngroute

just have a problem with an **Angular4** App... Indeed, I've got masives external scripts files which work on theme I'm currently working on.

Problem is the following.
Script files are only trigger once (when they are load), but I need to fire them on certains page... How could I do that?
Delete and reload the script file? I'm pretty sure that is the baddest way to do... But I cannot find any other solution.

Could someone have an idea ?

Thank's

I've develop one service which allow me to load and remove script. It's working well, but I'm sure It's not the best solution...

**My Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';


interface ScriptObject {
    path: string;
    class?: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class ScriptsManagerService implements ScriptObject{
  path : string;
  class : string;

  private initIndexScriptPath = 0;
  private indexScriptPath:number  = 0;

  private nbFichierScriptLoaded: number = 0;
  private scriptsToLoad: Array<ScriptObject>;
  private scriptsToRemove: Array<ScriptObject>;

  private showMessageCallback:boolean = false;

  constructor() { 
  }


  /**
   * Fonction qui permet de charger dynamiquement des scripts sur une page
   * @param scriptsToLoad - Liste des scripts à charger
   * @param callbackMessage - Fonction de rappel pour afficher une réponse lorsque que les scripts sont chargés
   */
  public loadScriptsFiles = function(scriptsToLoad : Array<ScriptObject>, callbackMessage?: boolean) {
    if(typeof callbackMessage !== 'undefined')
      this.showMessageCallback = callbackMessage; 

    if(typeof this.scriptsToLoad === 'undefined')
      this.scriptsToLoad = scriptsToLoad; 




    this.iterateNextScript(scriptsToLoad[this.indexScriptPath], "Script added with success",  () =>{

      if( this.indexScriptPath < scriptsToLoad.length ) {

        // Charge le script à l'index défini
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = scriptsToLoad[this.indexScriptPath].path;

        if(typeof scriptsToLoad[this.indexScriptPath].class !== "undefined")
          script.className = scriptsToLoad[this.indexScriptPath].class;


        // Créer le nom de la class qui sera ajouté à la balise script
        let nameScript: Array<string> = scriptsToLoad[this.indexScriptPath].path.split("/");

        let uniqueNameScript = nameScript[nameScript.length - 1].replace(/\./g,"");
        uniqueNameScript = uniqueNameScript.replace(/-/g,"");
        uniqueNameScript = uniqueNameScript.replace(/_/g,"");
        uniqueNameScript = uniqueNameScript.toLocaleLowerCase();

        script.id = "addedScript-uniqueId-" + uniqueNameScript + "-" + [this.indexCssPath];


        // Récupère l'index suivant du script
        this.indexScriptPath++;


        // Ecoute l'évènement de chargement sur le script
        Observable.fromEvent(script,'load')
                    .subscribe(() => {
                      if(this.nbFichierCssLoaded == scriptsToLoad.length-1){
                        this.indexScriptPath = 0;
                        this.nbFichierScriptLoaded = 0;
                      }else{
                        this.loadScriptsFiles(scriptsToLoad, true);   
                        this.nbFichierScriptLoaded++;
                      }
                    }  
        );

      }
    }); 
  }


  public removeScriptsFiles = function(scriptsToRemove : Array<string>, callbackMessage?: boolean) {
    if(typeof callbackMessage !== 'undefined')
      this.showMessageCallback = callbackMessage; 

    if(typeof this.scriptsToRemove === 'undefined')
      this.scriptsToRemove = scriptsToRemove; 



    this.iterateNextScript(scriptsToRemove[this.indexScriptPath], "Script remove with success", () =>{
      if( this.indexScriptPath < scriptsToRemove.length ) {

        // Supprime le/les script(s) des class associées
        document.getElementsByClassName(scriptsToRemove[this.indexScriptPath]);
        this.loadScriptsFiles(scriptsToRemove, true);

        if(this.nbFichierScriptLoaded == scriptsToRemove.length-1){
          this.indexScriptPath = 0;
          this.nbFichierScriptLoaded = 0;
        }else{
          document.getElementsByClassName(scriptsToRemove[this.indexScriptPath]);
          this.removeScriptsFiles(scriptsToRemove, true);   
          this.nbFichierScriptLoaded++;
        }

        // Récupère l'index suivant du script
        this.indexScriptPath++;
      }
    }); 
  }




  private iterateNextScript = function(msg, textMessage, callback) {
    if(this.indexScriptPath < this.scriptsToLoad.length){
      console.log(textMessage  + " : " + msg);
      callback();
    }    
  }

}
```

**My Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ScriptsManagerService } from '../../../app/services/script_manager/scripts-manager.service';
import { CssManagerService } from '../../../app/services/css_manager/css-manager.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ae-sidebar-composant',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-composant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-composant.component.css']
})

export class SidebarComposantComponent {

  constructor(private scriptsService: ScriptsManagerService, private cssService: CssManagerService) { }

  ngAfterContentInit(){

    this.scriptsService.loadScriptsFiles([
      { 
        path : "/assets/plugins/modernizr.custom.js" 
      },
      { 
        path : "/assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" 
      },
      { 
        path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js" 
      },
      { 
        path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
      },
      { 
        path : "/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-easy.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/handlebars/handlebars-v4.0.5.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-bez/jquery.bez.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-ios-list/jquery.ioslist.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-actual/jquery.actual.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/classie/classie.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/switchery/js/switchery.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap3-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-autonumeric/autoNumeric.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-form-wizard/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js"  
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"  
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/summernote/js/summernote.min.js"  
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-typehead/typeahead.bundle.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-typehead/typeahead.jquery.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/handlebars/handlebars-v4.0.5.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/bootstrap-collapse/bootstrap-tabcollapse.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/Bootstrap/jquery-datatable-bootstrap.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/datatables.responsive.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/lodash.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/js/datatables.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/js/tables.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/pages/js/pages.min.js" 
      },
      { 
          path : "/assets/js/scripts.js" 
      }
    ], false);
      }
    }
```